# Filter by list id use dynamic query in nest elastic client

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I build dynamic query to filter by list id in nest elastic client same that

```
List<QueryContainer> mustQuery = new List<QueryContainer>();
            if (lstId.Count > 0)
            {
                mustQuery.Add(new QueryStringQuery()
                {
                    DefaultField = "product.id",
                    Query = String.Join(" ", lstId)
                });
            }
```

However, if **lstId** have many item, the query string will be too long and return error.

I can use `client.GetMany<product>(lstId)` to filter by list id but in this case, i want use dynamic query because i can search by other fields same that or add more conditions.
Please help me.

Comment: what do you mean by "_the query string will be too long and return error._"? What type of error are you seeing?